# how to loop over stdin or file in bash ? (with one single loop)

Tags: bash

I have script that can loop over a give file

```
while IFS=";" read -r a b c
do
  ...
done <"$file"
```

but I also want user to use stdin..
I know how to read stdin:

```
while IFS=";" read -r a b c
do
  ...
done <"${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

I want to keep loop content unchanged, and to work on the "done" statement to feed it from a file or from stdin.

I am trying to do something like

```
if [[ "$usefile"=="yes" ]]; then
  data="$file"
else
  data="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
fi

while IFS=";" read -r a b c
do
  ...
done <"$data"
```

But of course, it does not work at data="${1:-/dev/stdin}" line... the ${} is replaced and fails

tried to use data to store either filename or stdin name.

Comment: `But of course, it does not work at data="${1:-/dev/stdin}" line... the ${} is replaced and fails` is unclear to me. What does fail and in what way exactly? Note that `[[ "$usefile"=="yes" ]]` is not `[[ "$usefile" == "yes" ]]`

Comment: it fails like this :
```#!/bin/bash
$data="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```
./test.sh: line 2: =/dev/stdin: No such file or directory

Comment: There is no `$data=...` in your code. You posted `data=...`. You do not assign variable with `$data=` in shell, just `data=` to assign, no `$`.

Comment: indeed this is typo in my last comment, code to be picked from original post. please focus on this one. Simply typing data="${1:-/dev/stdin}" does produce the error, there is no need to type the rest of the script :) I tried to escape "$" by "\$" but it didn't made the trick.

Comment: I get no error when typing `data="${1:-/dev/stdin}"`  in my terminal. Are you sure you are using Bash? What is the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`? `does produce the error,` What error? Please post verbatim the whole error message, at best edit your question and include the error message.

Comment: not from terminal, from a script!

Comment: I get no error when executing `data="${1:-/dev/stdin}"` as part of a script. Are you sure you are using Bash from a script? What is the output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` from the script? Please post verbatim the error message you are getting from the script. What is your shebang in the script?

Comment: yes it's bash "4.2.46(2)-release" from RHEL7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, the done statement have to be changed into

`done < "${file:-/dev/stdin}"`

if file is provided, it will loop over file content, otherwise it will loop over /dev/stdin

Final script:

```
# note: leave file empty to loop over stdin.

while IFS=";" read -r a b c
do
  ...
done < "${file:-/dev/stdin}"
```